# Which is grammatically correct, and why? Possessive vs. noun adjunct

Tags: grammar

Which is grammatically correct: "He remarked that oftentimes oracles’ predictions are unspecific" or "He remarked that oftentimes oracles predictions are unspecific" (without the apostrophe)? Why?

Comment: Since apostrophes are silent, and grammar has to do with speech, not punctuation, both are grammatically correct.There's no difference in meaning in any event.

Comment: @JohnLawler The second one is punctuated incorrectly though, isn't it? The oracles do 'own' the predictions in a sense.

Comment: @BoldBen In what sense would you say the oracles 'own' the predictions? Honest question, I'm trying to understand the scope of possession in English. Thanks!

Comment: Possession is just one sense of the genitive relation, which can apply to humans and their body parts and other inalienable possessions like a personality and a family. Many languages consider alienable possessions like cars and emotions and political beliefs as not being real possession at all, and treat them differently. Latin grammars distinguish the genitive of possession, the genitive of time, the genitive of quality, the genitive of the whole, the genitive of quantity, and others. In English, _of_ is the unmarked word linker, and often doesn't mean more than that.

Comment: @John Lawler Could you please give a reference for the claim that grammar does not include punctuation? So, is there any aspect in which any of my examples is incorrect?

Comment: @Philosopherofscience The oracles made their predictions so, in that sense, they 'own' them so the word "oracles" in "oracles' predictions" takes a plural possessive apostrophe. This does not imply _legal_ ownership as "Peter's shirt" implies that he has legal title to it. Works of art are still regarded as the work of the artist even though the purchaser owns them. If Elon Musk bought a Van Gough sunflower painting it would still be "one of Van Gough's Sunflowers" even though Van Gough is long dead but it would also be "Elon Musk's Van Gough" or even "Elon Musk's Sunflower painting".

Comment: @BoldBen Super clear, thank you!